# android/Webview/ava get code to sync methods wait for others output

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, webview

I have two methods method A and method B.

My target is achieve output of Javascript in same method A which called it.See sample code

```
Webview webview;
void onCreate(Bundle B){
   super.onCreate(B);
 
   webview.addJavascriptInterface(this,"android");
   A();
}

void A(){
   webview.loadUrl("javascript: android.B(100);");
   //I expect here output of B() which is output of Javascript
   int aa = ????;


}

@JavascriptInterface
int B(int b){
   return b;
}
```

On A() is called, javascript executed on webview, then B() is called by javascript.

I want to do javascript continues the code where it executed. Suggest for "????".